# MongoDB query to make key-value with existing values

Tags: mongodb

My database has:

```
document1: {id: 'a', value: 1},
document2: {id: 'b', value: 2},
document3: {id: 'c', value: 3},
```

And I need get

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Could I do it using only mongo commands?

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject

Comment: @srhuevo : Are those values of a field w.r.t. different docs or different docs itself or different fields in a doc..

Comment: You can use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) aggregation operator to extract the key-value pairs from both the fields, and put them together as you need.

Comment: sorry, each value is a different document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "value": {
        "$push": { "k": "$id", "v": "$value" }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OSUo19KNbDz)